# Using moodle 3.3.2 over custom docker image with fpm: endless 303 redirect loop

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, moodle

I am trying to create an alpine-fpm based package for [this](https://github.com/ellakcy/docker-moodle/tree/dev) project But I cannot make the alpine_mysql based image to run via an nginx no matter how hard I tried. The problem I get is that the mooodle installation does a redirect loop therefore the browser does not serve the moodle.

The nginx configuration is in [this](https://github.com/ellakcy/docker-moodle/blob/dev/conf/nginx/nginx.conf) file whilst I tried also this option without success (not commited changes yet):

```
events {
  worker_connections  768;
}

http {
  include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  charset  utf-8;

  gzip  on;
  gzip_disable  "msie6";
  client_max_body_size 10000M;

      server {
        listen  80 default_server;
        server_name  _;

        root  /var/www/html;
        index  index.php;

        location / {
          try_files  $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
          fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
          fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
          fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
          fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
          fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
          fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
          fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
          fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
          fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
          fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
          fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
          fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
          fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
          fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
          fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
          fastcgi_read_timeout 600;

          fastcgi_intercept_errors  on;
          fastcgi_pass  moodle_mysql_alpine:9000;
        }
      }
    }
```

Also my docker-compose is [this](https://github.com/ellakcy/docker-moodle/blob/dev/docker-compose.yml) file, on it you can focus on these lines:

```yml
  #Basic alpine fpm image
  alpine_fpm_base:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/fpm_alpine/Dockerfile_base
    image: ellakcy/moodle:alpine_fpm_base

  moodle_mysql_alpine_db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MOODLE_DB_NAME}"
      MYSQL_USER: '${MOODLE_MYSQL_USER}'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${MOODLE_MYSQL_PASSWORD}'

  # Mysql Enabled image

  nginx:
   image: nginx:alpine
   ports:
     - "7070:80"
   volumes:
     - './conf/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro'
   links:
     - 'moodle_mysql_alpine'
   volumes_from:
     - 'moodle_mysql_alpine'

  moodle_mysql_alpine:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/fpm_alpine/Dockerfile_mysql
    image: ellakcy/moodle:mysql_maria_fpm_alpine
    links:
      - "moodle_mysql_alpine_db:moodle_db"
      - "alpine_fpm_base"
    environment:
      MOODLE_DB_HOST: "moodle_mysql_alpine_db"
      MOODLE_DB_NAME: "${MOODLE_DB_NAME}"
      MOODLE_DB_USER: '${MOODLE_MYSQL_USER}'
      MOODLE_DB_PASSWORD: "${MOODLE_MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
      MOODLE_ADMIN: "${MOODLE_ADMIN}"
      MOODLE_ADMIN_PASSWORD: "${MOODLE_ADMIN_PASSWORD}"
MOODLE_URL: "http://0.0.0.0:7070"
```

I try to run it via `docker-compose rm && docker-compose up moodle_mysql_alpine_db moodle_mysql_alpine nginx` command. Also further investigation of the issue on the nginx's logs shows that for some reason the nginx throws 303 redirect:

```
172.25.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2017:21:02:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 303 429 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"
172.25.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2017:21:02:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 303 429 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"
172.25.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2017:21:02:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 303 429 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"
172.25.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2017:21:02:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 303 429 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"
172.25.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2017:21:02:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 303 429 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"
172.25.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2017:21:02:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 303 429 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"
172.25.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2017:21:02:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 303 429 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"
172.25.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2017:21:02:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 303 429 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"
172.25.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2017:21:02:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 303 429 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"
172.25.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2017:21:02:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 303 429 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"
```

Do you fellows have any idea why that happens?

## Edit 1:

I tried to follow an nginx configuration based on https://moopi.uk/mod/page/view.php?id=78 resulting to this:

```
events {
  worker_connections  768;
}

http {
  include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  charset  utf-8;

  gzip  on;
  gzip_disable  "msie6";
  client_max_body_size 10000M;

  server {
    listen  80 default_server;
    server_name  _;

    root  /var/www/html;
    index  index.php;

    location / {
      try_files  $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
      fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
      fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
      fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
      fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
      fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
      fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
      fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
      fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_intercept_errors  on;
      fastcgi_pass  moodle_mysql_alpine:9000;
    }
  }
}
```

Still I get redirection loop.

## Edit 2:

As requested with the command `curl -iv http://0.0.0.0:7070` I get the following response:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://0.0.0.0:7070/
*   Trying 0.0.0.0...
* Connected to 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) port 7070 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 0.0.0.0:7070
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
< Server: nginx/1.13.3
Server: nginx/1.13.3
< Date: Sun, 01 Oct 2017 09:41:21 GMT
Date: Sun, 01 Oct 2017 09:41:21 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.23
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.23
< Location: http://0.0.0.0:7070
Location: http://0.0.0.0:7070
< Content-Language: en
Content-Language: en

< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Redirect</title>
* Connection #0 to host 0.0.0.0 left intact
</head><body><div style="margin-top: 3em; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center;">This page should automatically redirect. If nothing is happening please use the continue link below.<br /><a href="http://0.0.0.0:7070">Continue</a></div></body></html>
```

## Edit 3:

I tried to use the configuration based on https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Nginx and resulted this nginx configuration:

```nginx
events {
  worker_connections  768;
}

http {
  include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  charset  utf-8;

  gzip  on;
  gzip_disable  "msie6";
  client_max_body_size 10000M;

  server {
    listen  80 default_server;
    server_name  _;

    root  /var/www/html;
    index  index.php;

    location / {
      try_files  $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
      fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include   fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

      fastcgi_pass  moodle_mysql_alpine:9000;
    }

    location /dataroot/ {
      internal;
      alias /var/moodledata; # ensure the path ends with /
    }

  }
}
```

But I still get the 303 redirect loop.

Comment: Do a `curl -v <urlwithproblem>` and add the output of the same to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end in nginx it the following configuration:

```
events {
  worker_connections  768;
}

http {
  include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  charset  utf-8;

  gzip  on;
  gzip_disable  "msie6";
  client_max_body_size 10000M;

  server {
    listen  7070;
    server_name  _;
    proxy_redirect    off;

    root  /var/www/html;
    index  index.php;

    location / {
      try_files  $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
      fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      #fastcgi_index index.php;
      include   fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_pass  moodle_alpine_fpm_mysql:9000;
    }

    location /dataroot/ {
      internal;
      alias /var/moodledata/; # ensure the path ends with /
    }

  }
}
```

For soem reason after debugging the moodle's source code for some reason it gets the nginx's listening port therefor the url I set to moodle's config (`http://0.0.0.0:7070`) was not working.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the answer was to set the following option in config.php

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'https://my-site';
$CFG->sslproxy = true;
```

The 'sslproxy' option means that the proxy or load balancer will handle ssl and thus prevents the endless 303 redirects (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS).